# Box plot with Line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, boxplot, line-plot

I want to merge a line plot with 12 box plot. I can plot both of them in a figure. But the line plot position is not matching with Box plot. Please suggest. Figure is attached

[image]

Code:

```
clc
clear
[data header]=xlsread('Dry and Wet Spell Length.xlsx');
RCP26_JHT=(mean(data(1:4:16,:),1));
RCP26_QIN=mean(data(2:4:16,:),1);
RCP26_SCA=mean(data(3:4:16,:),1);
RCP26_WOL=mean(data(4:4:16,:),1);
RCP45_JHT=mean(data(18:4:33,:),1);
RCP45_QIN=mean(data(19:4:33,:),1);
RCP45_SCA=mean(data(20:4:33,:),1);
RCP45_WOL=mean(data(21:4:33,:),1);
RCP85_JHT=mean(data(35:4:50,:),1);
RCP85_QIN=mean(data(36:4:50,:),1);
RCP85_SCA=mean(data(37:4:50,:),1);
RCP85_WOL=mean(data(38:4:50,:),1);
ANUSPLIN_JHT=mean(data(52,1:23));
ANUSPLIN_QIN=mean(data(53,1:23));
ANUSPLIN_SCA=mean(data(54,1:23));
ANUSPLIN_WOL=mean(data(55,1:23));
AN_Data=repmat([ANUSPLIN_JHT,ANUSPLIN_QIN,ANUSPLIN_SCA,ANUSPLIN_WOL]',1,3);
B=reshape(AN_Data',1,12);
y=1:12;
p=plot(B,'k-s', 'MarkerFaceColor','k');
legend(p,'Obs','Location','north');
hold on
xlim = get(gca,'XLim');
positions=[1,1.25,1.5, 2,2.25,2.5 3 3.25 3.5, 4 4.25,4.5];
boxplot([RCP26_JHT',RCP45_JHT',RCP85_JHT',RCP26_QIN',RCP45_QIN',RCP85_QIN',RCP26_SCA',RCP45_SCA',RCP85_SCA', RCP26_WOL', RCP45_WOL',RCP85_WOL'],'positions', positions);

color = ['b','c','y','b','c','y','b','c','y','b','c','y'];
h = findobj(gca,'Tag','Box');
for j=1:length(h)
   patch(get(h(j),'XData'),get(h(j),'YData'),color(j),'FaceAlpha',.5);
end
legend('Obs','RCP 8.5', 'RCP 4.5', 'RCP 2.6');
h1=findobj(gca,'tag','Outliers');
delete (h1);
set(gca,'xtick',[mean(positions(1:3)) mean(positions(4:6)) mean(positions(7:9)) mean(positions(10:12)) ]);
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'JHT','QIN','SCA','WOL'});
set(gca,'XLim',xlim);
hold off
```

Comment: Please show us the code you used to create this plot.  It's impossible to see where the problem is without it.

Comment: I added the code please see the code. Thanks !